# Python CSV Logic

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a python program that tests if certain cells in a csv have the value 4, and if they do, it should write that whole row to a csv file called grade4.csv. This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
with open('register-all-subs-2020-05-31.csv') as csvDataFile:
      csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
      data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvDataFile)]
      r=0
      c=0
      for r in range(33):
           for c in range(7):
                 print(data[r][c])
```

However, I can't figure out how to go about testing certain values in the cell and writing the row to a csv. It would be great if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and modify it little bit according to your purpose :

```
def check_four(row):
    for cell in row:
        if "4" in cell:
            return True
    return False


def main():
    with open("file.csv","r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    rows = data.split(",")
    new_rows = []   
    for row in rows:
        if check_four(row):
            new_rows.append(row)
    new_data = ','.join(new_rows)
    with open("grade4.csv","w") as f:
        f.write(new_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```